# What kind of magnetic water conditioner can industrial sinter plant use?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, chemical-engineering, mechanical

As you can see in the below shematic, the magnetic water conditioners can be used for the pipes of incoming process water on sinter plants to reduce surface tension of water and get fuel consumption benefits. But I researched and couldn't find any type of this conditioners/armatures .

[image]

Look at first article about this: https://www.steeltimesint.com/contentimages/features/KumarIronMaking2.pdf
This looked unrealistic to some engineers that magnetic water conditioner is not really exist thing.

But..

Please also read: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S187538921400532X/pdf?md5=3846d794d248117cceb8e706f4b1489f&pid=1-s2.0-S187538921400532X-main.pdf

The above article looks more realistic, so is this magnetic charging chute can reproduce for water as well?

Is there any industrial-scale magnetic water conditioner exist?

Comment: This seems a bit confused. These inline magnetic filters are common in UK domestic heating systems to trap any metal particles released by internal corrosion, but "reducing surface tension" seems a strange idea.

Comment: @alephzero please read this: https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=2_3ODQAAQBAJ&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=magnetic+water+conditioner+sinter&source=bl&ots=rncDAtpN3P&sig=ACfU3U14en0Yzx6uoaUtxCEN3dZHBUgu7g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsjY_L-f3nAhVy1qYKHfMBA8QQ6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=magnetic%20water%20conditioner%20sinter&f=false     it says they tested it and this magnetic field effects sinter plant productivity, and this: https://www.steeltimesint.com/contentimages/features/KumarIronMaking2.pdf , so you mean this is just an illusion?

Comment: The first link is to a page that I can't view. At the end of the second link it says "The application of a magnetic field to the water arranges the random orientation of the water molecules into a single direction, causing the water molecules to condense." Magnetic particle filters are a real thing, but that's just woo-woo IMO. Graphs labelled "magnetic water" don't much credibility either.

Comment: @alephzero I barely agree with you, when I try to search for magnetic industrial water conditioners i get nothing like that but some in alibaba[dot]com. Maybe that equipment has a different name? did you look at figure 5 water pipes?also look: 56-57 https://issuu.com/quartzmetals/docs/steel_times_international_april_201

Comment: This scam has been around for 40 years. Whenever someone tries to do an objective test , A satisfactory test location can not be found . NACE ( National Association of corrosion Engineers ) may have reviews available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mystical claims for magnetic water conditioning have been given a special technical term to describe them, used only by real hip engineers.

It is *jive- _ss baloney*.

Comment: Okay, but can you describe how did they do these tests and generated those graphs? All are scam? 1)https://www.steeltimesint.com/contentimages/features/KumarIronMaking2.pdf                        2) https://issuu.com/quartzmetals/docs/steel_times_international_april_201              
3) https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=2_3ODQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA235&dq=magnetic%20water%20conditioner%20sinter&pg=PA235#v=onepage&q=magnetic%20water%20conditioner%20sinter&f=false

Comment: Also please look at this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S187538921400532X/pdf?md5=3846d794d248117cceb8e706f4b1489f&pid=1-s2.0-S187538921400532X-main.pdf  the similar magnetic equipment..